# difference between "work with google assistant" and "built-in"? thanks

Tags: google-assistant-sdk

Is there any doc or people can tell me the difference between "work with google assistant" and "built-in"? If a new smart device going to add google assistant in, what should we do based on these 2 different ways?

Comment: Can you add some more context around your question, such as docs and what language you are using?

Comment: emmm, for example a company wanna make new smart speaker with Google Assistant integrated in, Google suggest 2 ways, "work with the Google Assistant" and "built-in", i would like to know the difference (of business maybe?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building IoT devices for the Google Assistant fall into two categories.

You can have the Google Assistant [built into](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/overview) your device. This would let you talk directly to your device and invoke custom device actions. It would not really integrate with a consumer's existing devices.

Alternatively, you can [work with](https://developers.google.com/smarthome) the Google Assistant. This would be for a device that you control using an existing Google Assistant surface like a Google Home or a phone. This simplifies the integration work, as you don't need to worry about all the voice management, and may be better for integrating into other voice ecosystems.

Comment: Hey Nick, do you know how to achieve "google assistant built-in" and "work with the google assistant" badge? thanks

Comment: What badges are you talking about?